# How does petrify affect Shardminds in 4E D&D?

Tags: dnd-4e

I need to know if Shardminds can be affected by any form of petrifaction in 4E D&D. Does it not work because they're already made of crystals? Does it work by changing them into regular stone? Or, does it not work because it turns them into regular stone which their consciousness then animates?

I believe that rules-wise they could be affected because they don't have a written immunity to it, but I want to know what logic would dictate, to placate an adamant Shardmind PC.

Comment: "adamant Shardmind PC" so to speak! ;)

Comment: :P Believe it or not, I didn't notice the pun when I wrote the question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You already answered your own question:

> I believe that rules-wise they could be affected because they don't have a written immunity to it, but I want to know what logic would dictate to placate an adamant Shardmind PC.

The rules don't say that a Shardmind is immune to petrification, so it isn't. What that looks like is up to the DM.

4e is very much a "rules first" kind of system; the narrative follows what the rules say happens.

Comment: I guess you're right. The rules should come first. Thanks for the prompt response. This site is awesome.

Comment: The good news is that you've already come up with a plausible "game world" explanation as well.